# HitTestObject issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a bit of a problem with `hitTestObject` in Flash.

I have these tiles generated on the screen and I have a player added to the tiles. I created an invisible square bitmap for the player, which is the size of the tile so it can register whether it is hitting the tile completely. The problem is, it is registering hit test from tiles that aren't even next to the player. The link below, My mouse is over the tile that is highlighted, and I have a trace that checks the hitTest between the player and the current Tile that it's on.

http://postimg.org/image/6so3npm19/

Here is the code for the bitmap. I've been playing around with the x and y position and the size of it.

```
visionArea.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1.0);
visionArea.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 85, 85);
visionArea.graphics.endFill();
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
matrix.scale(1, 0.5);
visionArea.transform.matrix = matrix;

addChild(visionArea);
visionArea.mouseEnabled = false;
visionArea.visible = false;
visionArea.x = 4;
visionArea.y = -21;
```

When I click a tile and the player is next to it, I move it to that tile.

```
if (player.visionArea.hitTestObject(event.currentTarget as Tile))
{
    player.x = (event.currentTarget.x)+55;
    player.y = (event.currentTarget.y)+20;
}
```

I also have an enemy on the screen (the green tile). I'm trying to have the player not be able to go on the tile that the enemy is on, but sometimes it would work, sometimes it wouldn't.

```
if (enemy.enemyVisionArea.hitTestObject(event.currentTarget as Tile))
{
    player.x != (event.currentTarget.x)+55;
    player.y != (event.currentTarget.y)+20;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that something is off with your `visionArea`. Can you post more details about that? Can you try to trace that before the hittest? Something like: `trace("VisionArea width: " + visionArea.width + " and height: " + visionArea.height);`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Joetjah. I've traced it. VisionArea width: 120.2 and height: 60.1
The tiles themselves are 120 and 60. Maybe since the vision overlaps?

Comment: Yeah, that'll overlap to the next Tile. But I'm also wondering where the `+55` and `+20` come from in your movement code?

Comment: Go figure you stand at the edge of the tile. The Tile has a 120 width. The Tile next to that Tile is an enemy. If you go over 120, you hit the Tile next to it. But I'm also wondering where it starts from. If it starts from the centre, it's no problem.

Comment: Oh, I see it is solved haha.

Comment: I was following a character tutorial, which had the registration point in the middle instead of the top left. So I added +55 and +20 to center the character to the tiles x and y

Comment: Well the vision hitting the tile next to it is fine, the problem is the tile 2 spaces over.

Comment: 55 isn't half of 120 and 20 isn't half of 60. Did you consider this?

Comment: The bitmap square known as vision is created in code, it isn't an actual image in the movieClip. I will post that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (player.visionArea.hitTestObject(event.currentTarget as Tile) && !enemy.enemyVisionArea.hitTestObject(event.currentTarget as Tile))
{
    player.x = (event.currentTarget.x)+55;
    player.y = (event.currentTarget.y)+20;
}
```

I've never seen anyone use != as an assignment operator.

Comment: Nice call, this replaces the two if-statements by just one.

Comment: Wow, I mean I'm not a genius actionscripter, but I'm a dunce for not considering this.